# XML: If a XmlNodeList.Count >= 1, will XmlNodeList.Item(#) ever be null?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to figure out if I have an XmlNodeList object, and Count is greater or equal to 1, will its "Item" object ever be null?

If so, how can I check if it is null before calling its "HasChildNode" property?

```
if (XmlNodeList.Item(0).HasChildNodes)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No item will never be `null` in the example you give - usually you would access the items differently though - either by index directly (if you need the index):

```
XmlNodeList nodes= ...
for (int itr = 0; itr < nodes.Count; itr++)
{
   //do something with nodes[i]
}
```

or with `foreach`:

```
XmlNodeList nodes= ..
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   //do something with node
}
```

Comment: XmlNodeList is just a collection of XmlNode. Generally it can contain null items.

Comment: `XmlNodeList` is an abstract class - afaik only selected  methods of `XmlNode` return an instance, and all of those guarantee that no node in the collection is `null`. I guess you could create your own class derived from `XmlNodeList` that does that but I don't think it's very practical to think that way, nor have I ever seen sample code that does indeed check for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not null even if there is no node inside the XmlNodeList! You may try "**Count**" method to check:

```
XmlNodeList TheXmlNodeList = GetMenuItems();
if (TheXmlNodeList.Count > 0)
{
    //has node
}
else
{
    //do not have node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer the (contrafactual?) "if so" question:

```
if (XmlNodeList.Item(0) != null && XmlNodeList.Item(0).HasChildNodes)
```